# Dart function to convert full width ASCII characters into normal ASCII characters

Tags: flutter, dart

I wish to convert [full width ASCI](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms/utf8test.htm) to ordinary ASCII characters. Do we have any built-in method or package to convert it?

Comment: Check the official convert library https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is such a method.

If not, you could write your own String Extention.

### Extension

```dart
extension StringX on String {
  
  static const fullWidthRegExp = r'([\uff01-\uff5e])';
  static const halfWidthRegExp = r'([\u0021-\u007e])';
  static const halfFullWidthDelta = 0xfee0;

  String _convertWidth(String regExpPattern, int delta) {
    return replaceAllMapped(RegExp(regExpPattern),
    (m) => String.fromCharCode(m[1]!.codeUnits[0] + delta)
    );    
  }
  
  String toFullWidth() => _convertWidth(halfWidthRegExp, halfFullWidthDelta);
  String toHalfWidth() => _convertWidth(fullWidthRegExp, -halfFullWidthDelta);

}
```

### Usage

Usage with the range of characters I considered in the String Extension.

```dart
void main() {
  final myStr = '！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～';
  print(myStr);
  print(myStr.toHalfWidth());
  print(myStr.toHalfWidth().toFullWidth());
}
```

```
！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～
```

Comment: I think it is the perfect solution. However, I tried with it and when I output the string, it shows unknown character. Not sure which part goes wrong...

Comment: I tested with a usual full width Ａ and some regular alphabets and it become an unknown.

Comment: ok my bad, I accidentally remove the - in the delta parameter.